# Adding father after the child to Treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

There is an existing TreeView with a single item. Lets say that tree consist from some object that has it own id, and parentId. Now i would like to add to tree parent item, that child reference to it by its parentId.

The idea is to handle input with a large amount of nodes that is not always sorted by father first.

How can i repopulate my tree with maximum efficiency ?

Comment: You want to add to parent (the single item), childs or establish a new parent?

Comment: I want to add new parent (new item) and move an already existing item (its child) under its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/9f4ff8/add-root-node-child-node-to-a-treeview-selected-node-at-runtime-and-rename-the-selected-node/

1. There is a method "Add Root node"
2. There is a method "Add child node"

I think you are ok.